# How to create plots from within a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops, matplotlib

Syntax question only

I have read-in a large dataframe that is aligned by date. I have a 80+ list of dataframes that focus on key dates (time windows) that are of interest. I would like to loop over that list and plot each item (time window) with the x-axis as time and Y-axis as a particular column of data from each dataframe. All dataframes are of the same format and same column heading. I would then like my for loop to save each plot based on the list variable name.

However i am unsure how to pass these arguments in the correct syntax to a for-loop.

For below question i have assumed that temperature is the common constant across all dataframes and is the Y-axis that is to be returned for all DF's.

Closest relevant example i can find (line 21-24):

https://geo-python.github.io/2017/lessons/L7/pandas-plotting.html

```
In [21]: winter = daily['2012-12-01': '2013-02-28']

In [22]: spring = daily['2013-03-01': '2013-05-31']

In [23]: summer = daily['2013-06-01': '2013-08-31']

In [24]: fall = daily['2013-09-01': '2013-11-30']
```

```
List = [winter, spring, summer, fall]

for item in List:
    item.plot(item.index, 'Temperature')
    plt.savefig(item)
```

Amended for my particular case:

```
List = [newdf,newdf1]

for item in List:
    item.plot(item.index, 'Delta Port/STBD')
    plt.savefig(item)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-5-33c93322b048>", line 2, in <module>
    item.plot(item.index, 'Delta Port/STBD')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py", line 2941, in __call__
    sort_columns=sort_columns, **kwds)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py", line 1977, in plot_frame
    **kwds)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py", line 1766, in _plot
    elif not isinstance(data[x], ABCSeries):

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2682, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_array(key)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2726, in _getitem_array
    indexer = self.loc._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1327, in _convert_to_indexer
    .format(mask=objarr[mask]))

KeyError: "Int64Index([7230, 7231, 7232, 7233, 7234, 7235, 7236, 7237, 7238, 7239, 7240,\n            7241, 7242, 7243, 7244, 7245, 7246, 7247, 7248, 7249, 7250, 7251,\n            7252, 7253, 7254, 7255, 7256, 7257],\n           dtype='int64') not in index"
```

Comment: Did you try `item.plot(y='Temperature')`?

Comment: How would you pass the x-axis argument?

Comment: If `df` is a DataFrame. `df.plot(y="column name")` will plot the data in the column named `column name` against its index.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to call [pandas.DataFrame.plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) on `item`. You are passing `item.index` as an argument which is being interpreted as a list of column names to plot. Since the index numbers are not actually columns of `item`, you get the KeyError that you posted.

Try something like the following:

```
file_num = 1
for item in list: 
    item.plot(title='Delta Port/STBD')
    plt.savefig(f'Delta_Port_STBD_{file_num}.png')
    file_num += 1
```

Each file will be saved in the working directory of your script. Specify a full path before the filename to change this. You do not need to specify a `format` since it is deduced from the filename that ends in `.png`

See the link I posted for the arguments to `plot()` to change how `Delta Port/STBD` is displayed.

Comment: Yes that also works, you are just specifying a different string for the filename. What do you want the filename to look like?

Comment: plt.savefig() requires filename to be pathlike or handle. The help files indicate that the format needs to be specified. However, i have tried a few approaches. Any ideas for the save filename part of the loop?  
   
    #plt.savefig("Graph" + str(item) +".png", format="PNG")
    #plt.savefig('Graph_{}.png'.format(item))   
    #plt.savefig(item, format='.jpg')

Comment: i would like the filename to be the same as the (list) item name (which is a dataframe). I tried passing the item name as a string but i keep getting errors returned. See above.

Comment: plt.savefig(str(item)) returns: ValueError: Format '027619\n\n[19920 rows x 15 columns]' is not supported (supported formats: eps, jpeg, jpg, pdf, pgf, png, ps, raw, rgba, svg, svgz, tif, tiff)

Comment: That is because `item` is a DataFrame. You need to come up with some system for naming your file with a string type (calling str(item) is not going to work, item is a reference to the data not the variable name). I will update my answer with a suggestion.